# How to automatically check a checkbox in React if I have the id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a set of checkboxes which the user checks to create some filters.  The user submits the form where they activate the filters.  This works fine however if the user goes back to the filterContainer the checkboxes do not keep their state and all checkboxes are unchecked.

How can check the checked checkboxes when the filter page is loaded.

If this was standard JS I would simply grab each dom element (with the correct id and then set the attribute to checked) Although I don't see a way of doing this in React.

Here is the code

Age data is simply an array and the handleClick function just sends the data to the store.

```
const ageData = [18+,18-35,36-50, 50+]

  <div className="filter__group-container">
    <h3>Age</h3>
    {ageData.map((item, index) =>[<div className="filter__group-item-container" key={index}>
      <CheckBox checked={need to send a boolean here somehow}
        handleClick={() =>this.handleClick({
          'id':item.id,
          'name': 'age_group_ids'
        })}
        key={index}
        id={'age:' + item.id} />
      <label key={item.description + index}>{item.description}</label>  </div> ])}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this?

```
const checkedIds = []

<CheckBox checked={checkedIds.includes(item.id)} ..
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: Will this work with an object ( I may have id's which are the same but name is different)

Comment: @marcuspetty the idea is to keep track of selected objects inside a state and then set checked status based on that array